# SCSS Containers grid

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to get only the containers grid from bootstrap4 grid system but I have an error on compiling and I really don't understand why ?

so this is the my custom scss file:

```
$grid-gutter-width:           30px !default;
$enable-grid-classes:       true !default;

$grid-breakpoints: (
'xs' : 0px,
'sm' : 576px,
'md' : 768px,
'lg' : 992px,
'xl' : 1200px
) !default;

$container-max-widths: (
sm: 540px,
md: 720px,
lg: 960px,
xl: 1140px
) !default;

@mixin make-container() {
width: 100%;
padding-right: ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
padding-left: ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

// Media of at least the minimum breakpoint width. No query for the smallest breakpoint.
// Makes the @content apply to the given breakpoint and wider.
@mixin media-breakpoint-up($name, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
$min: breakpoint-min($name, $breakpoints);
@if $min {
    @media (min-width: $min) {
    @content;
    }
} @else {
    @content;
}
}

// For each breakpoint, define the maximum width of the container in a media query
@mixin make-container-max-widths($max-widths: $container-max-widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
@each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
    max-width: $container-max-width;
    }
}
}

@if $enable-grid-classes {
.container {
    @include make-container();
    @include make-container-max-widths();
}
}

@if $enable-grid-classes {
.container-fluid {
    @include make-container();
}
}
```

and this is error:

```
    >>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
    error style.scss (Line 30: ("xs": 0px, "sm": 576px, "md": 768px, "lg": 992px, "xl": 1200px) isn't a valid CSS value.)
```

This should be compiled in some media-queries with given variables but somewhere the movie is broken and ... so please give me a hint or something

I'm using sass --watch for compilation

Comment: What is returned by the   breakpoint-min($name, $breakpoints)    do you have a sample of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the bootstrap files `functions` and `variables` before you import the grid system. The file for the grid system may be using mixins and variables from those two.